# find first occurrence in a random sequence run

Tags: excel

I have a row with cells containing 1s or 0s in a random sequence. In the next row, I have a function that finds the occurrence of a cell containing a 1 followed by a cell containing a 0.

```
=IF(AND(A2=1,B2=0), "TRUE","FALSE")
```

What I would like to do is echo out the value of the cell in row1 in the same column where the first occurrence of a 1 occurred in row2.

```
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
     |A    |B    |C    |D    |E    |F    |G    |
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
row1 |79.8 |76.4 |78.6 |77.1 |78.9 |71.2 |69.1 |
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
row2 |0    |1    |1    |1    |0    |1    |0    |
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
row3 |FALSE|FALSE|FALSE|FALSE|TRUE |FALSE|TRUE |
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

So in the above example, my function would return TRUE for E2 and G2, instead of TRUE though I want to return 76.4 for E3 and 71.2 for G3 since that is where the run of 1s started leading up to the 1 followed by a 0 sequence.

Is there a way to accomplish this in excel?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way: You can shorten `=IF(AND(A1=1,B1=0), "TRUE","FALSE")
` to `=AND(A1=1,B1=0)`

Comment: Hey thanks, I would like to return the value from B1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into cell C3 enter

```
=IF(AND(B2=1,C2=0),INDEX(1:1,1,1+LARGE(COLUMN($A2:A2)*($A2:A2=0),1)))
```

then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter it as an array formula.
You may then copy cell C3 to D3:Z3.

result:
[image]

Comment: @Joshwa if you want me to explain anything just ask, no worries

Comment: thanks for your help. See edits in original question. I want to return the data from row1 where the run of 1s started in row2.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to return the value from another row, you can simply change "1:1" to whatever your row is, "7:7", for instance.